# Flash for IOS could not verify air sdk target version in application.xml

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

Howzit I have an IOS i-pad app on my pc that I am trying to install on my i-pad.  I have done it a few times with success but today I updated my certificates and it wont load.  When I clicked on flash it asked me to install an update which I clicked yes to and now I am getting this error.

When I looked at the xml page target for sdk I have the following line

```
<application xmlsn="http://ns.adobe.com/air/apllication/18.0">
```

When i go to the link I get an error page I am not sure if that is relevant I have never actually gone to that link before.

I checked under project, properties, under platform it is on 18.0. If I press on SDK it on the top it says, no sdk configured, and under that it has a lcal root to my custom flash sdk.

Comment: is that only appears for Air-IOS developing? did you try any older sdk? did you get same error?

Comment: Yes I only need to run the app on an i-pad, it is for personal use.  
If i change the sdk, do I change it in properties and in that line of the xml that i shared?

Comment: no. if every thing is normal, you have to only set target as **Air xx for IOS** from properties